# Right click menu for jface TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse, menu, listener, e4, treeviewer

I would like to show a simple right click menu for a TreeViewer. I found some examples (like this: [Context menu for TreeViewer based on selected node - SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207772/context-menu-for-treeviewer-based-on-selected-node-swt) ) but they seem quite complicated and long in code.

Is there any simple way to attach a right click menu to an TreeViewer?

Comment: Your reference is the correct way to do this.