# JFace ListViewer change selection on right click

Tags: java, swt, jface

I already have a working `ListViewer` with items in it and a working context menu.

However when I right-click on the `ListViewer` the context menu opens without changing the active selection to the item that has been right-clicked. For example, if I have 3 items and the first one is currently selected, no matter where I right-click the selection will not change. What I intend is that when the first item is currently selected and I right-click the third item then the third item should get selected (resulting in the context menu referring to the third item).

I already found an answer that deals with this problem (although it is for a `TreeViewer` it should work similarly for a `ListViewer`), but the solution (using CursorLocation) seems very dirty. Here's the question/answer I mentioned: [Jface TreeViewer add right click menu, depending on clicked node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682081/jface-treeviewer-add-right-click-menu-depending-on-clicked-node)

Is there a more elegant way to also trigger a new selection on right-click?

Comment: On which platform do you see this behavior?

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior in an e4 application. Or did you mean my OS? In that case Windows 10.